# Mongoose DocumentArray Types (with autogenerated mongoose typescript types with mongoose-tsgen)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having issues trying to create a new Document in ts (it works fine in js).

"mongoose": "^5.11.10",
"mongoose-tsgen": "7.1.3",
node: v16.15.1
npm: v8.11.0
tsc: Version 4.9.3

Also it is a problem in the latest version of mongoose (6.1.5) and mongoose-tsgen (9.0.10)

Schema user.ts:

```
...
tikTokAdvertiserAccounts: [
    {
      id: String,
      name: String,
    },
  ],
...
```

I get this in my types.gen.ts:

```
...
export interface UserTikTokAdvertiserAccount {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}
...
```

I want to create it in my router:

```
...
let advertiserAccounts: UserTikTokAdvertiserAccount[] = [];
advertiserAccounts.push({id:'testid', name:'testname'});

user.tikTokAdvertiserAccounts = advertiserAccounts; // problem line

await user.save();
...
```

This throws an error:
`Type 'UserTikTokAdvertiserAccount[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentArray<UserTikTokAdvertiserAccountDocument>': isMongooseDocumentArray, create, id, $pop, and 8 more.`

So my question is how do I create this DocumentArray?

Interestingly if I try:

```
...
user.tikTokAdvertiserAccounts = new mongoose.Types.DocumentArray(
    advertiserAccounts
);
...
```

it seems to work out fine without Typescript complaining.

But if I try something on multiple lines then typescript gets confused:

```
const explicitAccounts = new mongoose.Types.DocumentArray(
    advertiserAccounts
);
user.tikTokAdvertiserAccounts = explicitAccounts;
```

`Type 'DocumentArray<Document<any, any, any>>' is not assignable to type 'DocumentArray<UserTikTokAdvertiserAccountDocument>'. Type 'Document<any, any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserTikTokAdvertiserAccountDocument': ownerDocument, parent, parentArray`

So my question is how should I create these sub document arrays on this user document? Or is there something wrong with the [mongoose-tsgen](https://github.com/francescov1/mongoose-tsgen/) library that should be different?

I was suggested by the author of this library to [cast to any](https://github.com/francescov1/mongoose-tsgen/issues/108), but I don't particularly like that!